# Bootstrap's pills displaying incorrectly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

When using the Bootstrap's `pills` component, the pill pane from which I navigate away just changes its opacity to zero, but it still takes up the original amount of space it did before, so the next pane is way below.

Code for the pills is this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="my-pills">
   <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#a">a</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#b">b</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="pill-content">
   <div class="pill-pane fade active in" id="a">
      <p>i am content a</p>
      <p>i am content a</p>
      <p>i am content a</p>
   </div>
   <div class="pill-pane fade" id="b">
      <p>i am content b</p>
      <p>i am content b</p>
      <p>i am content b</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And a working fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kw6sm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are pill- classes like you've used.  You want to use

```
data-toggle="pill"
```

but still use the tab classes, like

```
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="a">
      <p>i am content a</p>
      <p>i am content a</p>
      <p>i am content a</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
      <p>i am content b</p>
      <p>i am content b</p>
      <p>i am content b</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And you also missed a closing div, but I think that's immaterial.

Comment: Oh never mind, i changed tab-pane, but i missed out in tab-content... My bad, your answer is correct. Thank you.